# "/usr/bin/google-chrome" is not an ELF file

Tags: google-chrome, elf, instrumentation, ltrace

I am going to use ltrace for some applications like chrome but when I use it, I receive the following error message.

```
"/usr/bin/google-chrome" is not an ELF file
```

Does anybody know about the solution? I want to know what functions are exactly called by running an application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know about the solution?

```
file -L /usr/bin/google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

This tells you that `google-chrome` is a *shell* script. If you look inside, you'll see that it eventually invokes a real ELF binary (`/opt/google/chrome/chrome` on my system).

> I want to know what functions are exactly called by running an application.

The `ltrace` command will not show you that. It will only show you what *external* functions are getting called.

Answer (score 0):

fix: explicitly call the bash interpreter

```
ltrace -f -C bash -e $(which google-chrome) https://httpbin.dev/get
```

`bash -e` means: stop the bash script on error

IMO, this is a missing feature in [ltrace](https://gitlab.com/cespedes/ltrace/-/issues/16)

strace works with bash scripts

```
strace -ff google-chrome https://httpbin.dev/get
```